# How to execute two different functions at the same time using open mp in C

Tags: c, openmp

I'll be keeping this simple.

```
void func1(){
//gnarly math1
}
void func2(){
//gnarly math2
}
```

How do I execute this function in parallel using open mp?

EDIT: To be more precise at what the heck I'm writing about. If you have tried using ffmpeg (like trying to convert wav to mp3), it would show you the progress while converting it.

I'm trying to do it without multi threading like this:

```
        for(i=0;i<length;i++) {
            double t = (double) i / WAVFILE_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND;
            waveform[i] = volume*sin(frequency*t*2*M_PI);
            int progress = ( 900 )*b;
            if (progress == i){
                b++;
                printf("Writing: %d/%d amplitude=\"%d\"\n", i, length, __SUM);
            }           
        }
```

Output:

```
Writing: 900/88200 amplitude="825"
Writing: 1800/88200 amplitude="1530"
Writing: 2700/88200 amplitude="2011"
Writing: 3600/88200 amplitude="2198"
Writing: 4500/88200 amplitude="2064"
...
```

real source code is found at https://github.com/harieamjari/kunin

Comment: What have you yourself tried? How did you attempt work or not work? Can you perhaps share a [mcve] of your attempt? Also please take some time to refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Read an introduction to OpenMP, e.g. https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/omp-hands-on-SC08.pdf

Comment: @programmer well, I was trying to print the progress while writing the (wav) file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I totally forgotten about this question of mine, I've found a way a couple of days ago while reading this directives and construct for OPM: https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP-4.5-1115-CPP-web.pdf.

So:

```
#pragma omp parallel sections
        {
        #pragma omp section
        // func 1
        #pragma omp section
        {
        // func 2
        }
        }
```